# capturing data expired through Time to Live cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have a specific usecase where i want to perform some operations with the data that gets expired as a reason of providing TTL while inserting a row in cassandra.Currently i am not able to find any such provision where i can fetch the data that expired as a reason of TTL.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your data model to have the ttl'd date as part you can query on. You can than make a bulk job that processes them at intervals.

Or you can make a custom compaction strategy that triggers something when reading a column that has expired. It wont be "as it happens" but more as the columns are cleaned up/turned into tombstones.

Comment: Problem with that the job will have to query for TTl's which is not a Partition key and that will incur scatter gather problem. If i need to do that frequently that is an overhead for cassandra cluster as well. COmpaction strategy is something that can be used , but i would be easier use some strategy which is already in place and implemented rather than implementing something from scratch which can probably my last resort.

Comment: Just wondering this is a common problem with cassandra where i need to access data based on certain time range without any partition key, and i cannot find any suitable solution for the same. That is the reason i went for finding alternatives with TTL

Comment: its pretty normal to have time series data that has the timestamp (timeuuid) as the clustering id so they can be queried by time ranges

Comment: but even if Timeuuid is clustering key it won't be of much help because during query i need all records whose time is less than the current wakeup time for my scheduler who will periodically sweep the table.